# unable to create superuser in python Django

Tags: django, cassandra, pycharm, cassandra-3.0

I have read questions in Stackoverflow and googled, but no luck.

I am trying to create a superuser in pycharm(manage.py createsuperuser
) but got below error:

"cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: "

```
Not checking migrations as it is not possible to access/create the django_migrations table.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skum\PQP_Bridge\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 96, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 148, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:260 no viable alternative at input '.' (
...auth_user.date_joined FROM auth_user WHERE [auth_user]....)">
```

what am I doing wrong?

I am using Cassandra 3.0, Python Django 1.11.4, and pycharm.

Comment: post the full traceback

Comment: i have edited in question. does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not use: python manage.py createsuperuser using Cassandra It do not work with default django model. You need to use external library for the same. user module does not work with Cassandra by default

Please read document on data-stax or below given link. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cassandra-engine/